# How does encapsulating functions with brackets protect local variables from global variables?

Tags: javascript

I am a JavaScript beginner and I am struggling to understand this specific matter.

I think I can understand why functions are encapsulated with brackets, for instance, to transform an anonymous function declaration in an expression that can be immediately called. But I still don't understand why in all tutorials it's mentioned that they help protect local/internal variables from global scope variables.

For instance,

```
var greet = "ola";

var hey = function() {
    greet = "Hi!";
    console.log(greet);
};

console.log(greet); // Result: Ola
hey(); //Result: Hi!
```

The global scope `greet` keeps its value `ola` and the function's local `greet` is still `Hi!`.

If the function is encapsulated the global scope variable takes the value of the local value:

```
var greet = "ola";

(function hey() {
    greet = "Hi!"
    console.log(greet); // Result: Hi!
}());

console.log(greet); // Result: Hi!
```

Am I doing something wrong?

According to this example, wouldn't the variables in the global scope need protection from the encapsulated functions' variables?

Comment: Only if you declare a local variable inside the function ... `var greet = "Hi!"`.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try it out:)

Comment: Yes you are understanding that wrong. When you call hey what you do is assign a new value to greet and log the value. If you do your first examble but you call first hey() and then console.log(greet) you will see that the output is the same. Actually is what you do in your second example. To understant the scope you have to declare greet inside your function var greet = "Hi!" now greet is hidden of your global scope

Comment: Thank you!!! I understand now that I was doing something wrong. But still, how can the local variable be assigned with the value of the variable in the global scope? Isn't that the reason to hide local variables from global scope? The only way I see is if you don't declare any variable inside the function and take advantage of the scope chain. But for what I see any variable created inside a function will always keep its value protected from the values of the same variable in the global scope. I am really sorry if maybe I am complicating too much the subject:)

Comment: If you declare a new one inside the function then it has nothing to do with the outer one